# I am trying to create a summary by country for all the active fires and group them according to month

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a summary by country for all the active fires and group them according to month

```
SELECT
    date_part('month',acqdate) AS month
    ,date_part('year',acqdate) AS year
    , count(the_geom) as num_fires
FROM 
    merged_activefires
JOIN 
    "california_county.wgs84"
ON
    ST_Intersects(merged_activefires.the_geom, california_county.wgs84.the_geom)
WHERE
    california_county.wgs84.name = 'Modoc' --acqdate >'2013-12-31' and acqdate<'2014-02-01' 
    and
GROUP BY date_part('month',acqdate),date_part('year',acqdate)
ORDER BY month;
```

ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "wgs84"
LINE 4: ON ST_Intersects(merged_activefires.the_geom, california_cou...
                                                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "wgs84"
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 209

Comment: I've edited your post, and upon doing so it is clear there is a syntax error after the `WHERE` clause where you have an `and` that has only a `GROUP BY` immediately after it.

Comment: please reformat your code and put it into a code block.

Comment: can you supply the table definitions and maybe some example data as trying to replicate your error with other tables fails. The only possible mistake i currently see is the `and` at the end of the where clause which should be a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

In the JOIN clause, this syntax with double quotes around the entire name:

```
"california_county.wgs84"
```

means that this entire name designates a table, as opposed to a schema name followed by a dot followed by a table name, which could be written like this: `california_county.wgs84` or like that: `"california_county"."wgs84"`

On the other hand, this other part of your query:

```
california_county.wgs84.name
```

suggests exactly the opposite, that `california_county` is a schema name and `wgs84` is a table inside it, and `name` is a column of that table.

It is this contradiction that confuses the SQL parser.

Either `"california_county.wgs84"` is a table name in the current schema (an unfortunate choice, but valid) and you should consistently refer to it with `"california_county.wgs84"`,

or `california_county` is a schema and you should just use `california_county.wgs84` without any quote.